# Combinatorics Problem: Seating Arrangements for Four Married Couples

Tags: combinatorics

I have attempted a combinatorics problem and I would like to verify if my solution is valid. The problem is stated as follows:

Four married couples bought tickets for eight seats in a row at a show. Two people will sit next to each other only if they are a married couple or of the same gender. How many ways are there to seat the four married couples in those eight seats?

My solution is that there are two cases to consider: either all four couples sit together or two couples sit together and two couples sit separately.

Case 1: All four couples sit together. There are 4! ways to arrange the order of the couples. Within each couple, there are 2 ways to arrange the husband and wife. So there are a total of $$4! \times 2^4 = 384$$ ways for all four couples to sit together.

Case 2: Two couples sit together and two couples sit separately. There are $$\binom{4}{2} = 6$$ ways to choose which two couples will sit together. For each of these choices, there are $$2! \times 2^2 = 8$$ ways to arrange the order of the two couples and their husbands and wives. There are then $$4!$$ ways to arrange the order of the remaining four people (two husbands and two wives). So there are a total of $$6 \times 8 \times 4! = 1152$$ ways for two couples to sit together and two couples to sit separately.

Adding these two cases together, we find that there are a total of $$384 + 1152 = 1536$$ ways to seat the four married couples in those eight seats.

Does this solution look sound? I would appreciate any comments or suggestions

Comment: I'll name them, $a_m, a_f, b_m, b_f, c_m, c_f, d_m, d_f$ and use w, x, y, z to represent any member of a couple. what about $w_m,  x_m, y_m, z_m z_f,$ followed by any order of $w_f, x_f,, y_f$?
And variations of this?

With some thought I can probably find a variation which has 3 couples setting together.  I think breaking the whole exercise down by number of couples sitting together, 0 to 4 is possible and each has non zero orderings.

The idea that either two couples sit together or four couples sit together, seems incorrect.  I think there are multiple other cases.

Comment: Can you tell us the source of the problem ? It is not a simple one.

Comment: If the first 2 seats are Male followed by Female (of the same couple,) does the third seat need to go to a female?

Comment: In the modern world one should say "four married heterosexual couples" -- or dispense with this particular construction entirely.

Comment: The analysis of all four couples sitting together is certainly wrong, it allows arrangements like MFMFMFMF.

Comment: Counting Hamiltonian paths is hard in general, & I don't see why it should be nicer than usual in this case.

Comment: Result by brute force enumeration: $816$